# Truth function is unique

Tags: logic, solution-verification

If the truth functions $u,w : Π_0\mapsto \{0,1\}$ "agree" in all the variables $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ that appear in a sentence $φ$ then $\bar{u}(φ)=\bar{w}(φ)$.

> Where $Π_0=\{A_1,A_2,...\}$ , $A_i$ variables and $\bar{u},\bar{w}$ are the extensions to the set of all sentences, $Π_{n+1}=Π_n\cup\{ \neg φ| φ \in Π_n\}\cup\{φ\square ψ|φ,ψ \in Π_n , \square= \wedge, \vee ,\rightarrow \}$  and $Π= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} Π_n $
> $\: \:\bar{u},\bar{w}: Π\mapsto \{0,1\}$

---

(With induction)

$\cdot$ For the set $Π_0$ it's true by our hypothesis, $u(φ)=w(φ)$

$\cdot$ We assume it's true for the set $Π_n$

$\cdot $ we will show it's true for $Π_{n+1}$.

Let $φ,ψ \in Π_n$ from how $\bar{u},\bar{w}$ are defined we have  $\bar{u}(\neg φ)=\neg \bar{u}(φ)$, same $\bar{w}(\neg φ)=\neg \bar{w}(φ)$ but from our assumption we have $\bar{u}( φ)=\bar{w}( φ)$ $\Rightarrow \bar{u}( \neg φ)=\bar{w}(\neg φ) $

same logic applys to $\bar{u}( φ\square ψ)=\bar{u}( φ)\square \bar{u}( ψ)$ and $\bar{w}( φ\square ψ)=\bar{w}( φ)\square \bar{w}( ψ)$

Is my solution correct ?